# Book about time traveling teens

Tags: story-identification

I don't remember much about this story but I read it about 5 years ago, I borrowed it from the school library.

All I can remember is there was this stone in somebody's basement and then one of the character's father's went missing and he was trapped by Dracula back in the past

Help

Answer (score 4):

*[The Book of Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Book_of_Time_%28novel_series%29)* by Guillaume Prévost. 2006.

> .... Then his father vanishes. Sam waits for him to come home, but more than a week passes without a trace. He goes to the bookstore to search for clues. In a room he'd never seen before, he finds a strange red book called Crimes and Punishment During the Reign of Vlad Tepes, a stone statue with an odd circular indentation in it and a dusty coin with unreadable symbols. . . Eventually, with help from his cousin Lily, he is able to transport back home. Together, they learn more about the time-traveling statue and a man named Vlad Tepes, the inspiration behind the Dracula legends, who they believe is holding Allan in fifteenth-century Wallachia.